# Are performance reviews public information?

Tags: performance-reviews

Can other companies request performance reviews of an employee from other companies?

Can they request it from the employee or the previous employer?

Comment: Another company can request anything they want. It's unlikely they'd get it.

Comment: Why did the question get a down vote? Can I edit the question to be better?

Answer (score 2):

> Can other companies request performance reviews of an employee from
>   other companies?

**Yes** they can ask.

However, *they are highly unlikely to get such information* for fear of being sued.  Most of the time a company will confirm employment dates and **maybe** salary information -- but that is about it.

No one wants to be involved in a legal battle.  YMMV

Comment: What is the reason that they can be sued?

Comment: @milesmeow If your performance reviews are negative (or even if they aren't), you could sue your previous employer for lying and trying to make you look bad (even if they weren't) and preventing you from getting a job / unfairly ruining your reputation / etc. I don't know how likely you would be to WIN a lawsuit like that, but Americans, at least, seem to love trying.

Comment: @milesmeow Privacy, costing the person a job, slander, etc.  Lots and lots of reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Others answered the question but I wanted to add a touch to this. If the companies are owned by the same parent company, then they'd likely share HR and could look at your performance reviews.

Across different companies though, highly unlikely they'd share performance reviews. They'd call to ask about you, and your references maybe. Just be sure to talk to your references prior to make sure what they'd say.

Answer (score 1):

As others replied, yes they can. But I'd steer clear of any potential employer who would even bring this up. It's a very bad sign.

Comment: Why is it a very bad sign?

Comment: @MisterPositive For starters, it means they lack the ability to properly vet a candidate on their own.